# How to import parameter of type ANY?

Tags: abap

How can I put what a method - in this example `get_properties` - is giving me into a local variable when the type of the parameter is `ANY`?

```
"ES_ATTRIBUTES  Exporting   Type    ANY
some_object->get_properties( IMPORTING es_attributes = ????? ).
```

I tried to put it into this variable, but that didn't work:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS:
      <ls_attributes> TYPE any.
```

Answer (score 2):

In ABAP, it means that you may use a **data object** of any type (the simplest way is to declare it with `DATA`).

But it may be more restrictive according to the way the developer has coded his method.

Here, I recognize a method of WebUI Components (CRM, SOLMAN, …) so the data object must correspond to the "`some_object`" you are accessing. Do a debug of GET_PROPERTIES if you are not sure.

Comment: But if I declare a data object of some type how can I make sure no information gets lost from the import. some_object is very generic in this case and the exact entity it is referring to is set during runtime. Sometimes get_properties imports a structure with 3 fields, sometimes with 10 fields with different names.

Comment: Are you sure it's so generic? I think that you should tag your question with the WebUI or CRM tag. Or ask the question in the SAP "SCN" forum, and explain exactly the context (CRM, SOLMAN, etc.) You need to provide more information like which Business Entity you are using from the Business Object Layer (BOL). Note that you may also access one property at a time (if you know the name) with `GET_PROPERTY_AS_STRING`. You have transactions named something like *GENIL* to display the BOL entities and the DDIC structures used for the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Actually as a caller, you should know the type you want to import for this `ANY` parameter.

You have to know the protocol of `GET_PROPERTIES` and debug it to know the return type of the parameter. In your method, you create a `DATA REFERENCE` and have it assigned to a `ANY` field symbol.

```
Data:
      lr_data type ref to data.
Field-symbols:
      <lt_properties> type any. 

create data lr_data type TYPE_NAME.  'You should know the type
assign lr_data->* to <lt_properties>.
```

From my personal view, it is not a very good practice to define a method with `EXPORTING` parameter type `ANY`.

You either define a interface with IF_**_PROPERTY and you have a return TABLE of this interface.

or you return a name-value pair table. (From the method signature, it should return a TABLE, GET_**PROPERTIES**).